# SyntaxError discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm new to coding and I'm creating a Discord bot and I still get a Syntax error, here is the code:

```
import discord
import os 
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "/")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("Bot is online!")
  for filename in os.listdir("./cogs"):
    if filename.endswith(".py"):
      try:
        client.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")
        print(f"Loaded {filename}")
        except Exception as e:
          print(f"Failed to load {filename}")
          print(f"[ERROR] {e}")
          
          client.run("token")
```

And this is the error

```
  File "main.py", line 15
    except: Exception as e:
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Are you sure the code that you shared and used is the same?

Comment: Yes it is, I'm using the IDE from repl.it to get free hosting if that changes something.

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    client.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")
    print(f"Loaded {filename}")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Failed to load {filename}")
    print(f"[ERROR] {e}")
```

The except is supposeod to be outside the try chunk.
The except cannot find any try in the scope similarly the try doesnt find any except in its scope

The indentation can differ from ide to ide

Answer (score 0):

This might happen because **Python indentation** is not done right.
Your `try` and `except` is has a different indentation, make sure the `except` statement is at the same level as the `try` one.

Corrected code:

```
import discord
import os 
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "/")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("Bot is online!")
  for filename in os.listdir("./cogs"):
    if filename.endswith(".py"):
      try:
        client.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")
        print(f"Loaded {filename}")
      except Exception as e:
        print(f"Failed to load {filename}")
        print(f"[ERROR] {e}")
          
client.run("token")
```

[Reference on Python indentation.](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html)